# Получение высоты элементов View в onCreate()

Tags: android

Есть 4 элемента View не равноудалённых друг от друга по вертикали. Хочу, чтобы при загрузке приложения, паддинги между этимим элементами имели одинаковое соотношение на всех мобильных устройствах.

1. получаю высоту экрана.
2. хочу получить общую высоту всех этих 4х
       элементов в onCreate() (естественно
       возвращается ноль).
3. хочу вычесть из общей высоты экрана высоту общую
       высоту этих элементов, в итоге
       получу высоту пустого пространства.
4. пустое пространство хочу 
       разделить на расстояния между этими
       элементами.

Проблема во втором пункте. Есть ли способ получения высоты этих элементов View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размеры надо менять в `OnMeasure()` и потом вызывать `requestLayout()`

Answer (score 3):

Решил эту проблему у себя добавлением timer.start();

Суть в чем, пока элементы не отображены у них нет параметров высоты и ширины.
Можно переопределить методы OnMeasure() и  requestLayout().

Я пошел через таймер который стартует в конце onCreate.

Привожу свой код для наглядности.

```
    driverInfo        = ( LinearLayout ) this.findViewById( R.id.driverInfo );
    bodyContent       = ( LinearLayout ) this.findViewById( R.id.lLayoutContent );
    relativeLayoutMap = ( RelativeLayout ) this.findViewById( R.id.rLayoutMap );
```

---

```
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer( 100 , 100 )
   {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {

        int heigtDriver = driverInfo.getHeight();
        int heightMap   = relativeLayoutMap.getHeight();
        int contentBody = bodyContent.getHeight();

        if( heightMap != 0 && heigtDriver != 0 && contentBody != 0 )
        {
            if( heigtDriver > heightMap )
            {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( display.getWidth(), contentBody/2 );
                driverInfo.setLayoutParams( params );
            }
        }else{
            start();
        }

    }
};
```